# El Capitan - How to read Mac Os X Mail Accounts Informations

Tags: objective-c, macos, osx-elcapitan

I have an Application which uses the Content of the Accounts.plist.
After upgrade to Mac OS El Capitan / 10.11.1 the Accounts.plist isn't supported under the new Mail-Path.

Before:

```
/Users/[homefolder]/Library/Mail/v2/MailData/Accounts.plist
```

Now:

```
/Users/[homefolder]/Library/Mail/v3/MailData/*
```

How can i get the Mail-Account Details now ?

Comment: `sudo find /Users/[homefolder]/Library/Mail/ -iname "Accounts.plist"`

Comment: Thank you Thomas, but Accounts.plist is not supported anymore so i need a other source where i can get the Mail-Account-Informations from.

Comment: Which info do you need?

Comment: The content of the MailAccounts - Array. FullUserName, uniqueId, AccountName

Comment: Could it be in `com.apple.mail.plist` ?

Comment: there is no file named `com.apple.mail.plist`

Comment: The file is in the Mail Container: `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.mail/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.mail.plist`

Comment: although the file really is at `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.mail/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.mail.plist` in my case it didn't have the username in it (decompressed via sublime plugin `BinaryPlist`)

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled upon a cleaner way to do this. Refer SBSendMail(https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SBSendEmail/Introduction/Intro.html) for Apple's scripting bridge. Then to read smtp servers:

```
 MailApplication *mail = [SBApplication applicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.Mail"];

    /* set ourself as the delegate to receive any errors */
    mail.delegate = self;

    SBElementArray *smtpServers = mail.smtpServers;

    for (MailSmtpServer *server in smtpServers)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@ %@ %@ %@ %d", server.name, server.password, server.userName, server.serverName, server.port);
    }
```

You can read IMAP & POP account settings similarly.

Comment: But i can't find the `uniqueID` of the `MailAccount` Class (`MailApplication.accounts`). I need the `uniqueID` of the `MailAccount` to find the related signature in `AccountsMap.plist` under `/Users/[homefolder]/Library/Mail/v3/MailData/Signatures`